# remove tailing zeros in decimal

Tags: c#, .net, string, format, decimal

I want to remove the tailing zeros of a decimal. It is loaded from DB with precision 5.

I am using a culture where the comma (,) is the decimal point.

E.g:

- 10,00050 -> 10,0005
- 10,00000 -> 10
- 0,00000 -> 0
- 0,00001 -> 0,00001

I could use the [General ("G") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) but i don't want the scientific notation at any point.

BR, m.

Comment: 10,00000 -> 10 this is leaving a trailing zero.  Typo?

Comment: @PeteOakey Probably not, since it's before the decimal point. (I assume the OP is using a culture with `,` as decimal point.

Comment: @PeteOakey He's referring to trailing zeros to the right of the decimal separator.

Comment: OK - the comma is the decimal separator in this case.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
decimal d = 12.45600m;
d.ToString("0.#####");
```

Comment: That's not quite right: it'll round up to 12.45679. Suppose the Decimal was 456789000. How do you format it to 12.456789?

Comment: @ReacherGilt "loaded from DB with precision 5."

Comment: "your example is precision 6"

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is more elegant solution, but this worked on strings.

```
string[] decimals = {
                                "10,00050",// -> 10,0005
                                "10,00000",// -> 10
                                "0,00000",// -> 0
                                "0,00001",// -> 0,00001
                             };
        foreach (string dec in decimals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} -> {1}", dec, decimal.Parse(dec.TrimEnd(new char[] { '0' })));
        }
```

Comment: I recommend specifying `InvariantCulture` on both string<->decimal conversions. I don't trust cultures.

Answer (score -1):

Try "N", it adds commas if the number is a thousand or higher.